# XSLT - Dynamically populate data into input's value

Tags: xml, xslt

**Here are some simplified versions of my codes:**

**This is my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTFile.xslt"?>
<ResultSet>
  <RAMTemplatePart>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Title>STRUCTURAL DISCREPANCY IDENTIFICATION</Title>
    <RAMTemplateSection>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <RAMTemplatePartNumber>1</RAMTemplatePartNumber>
      <Title>PART 1 INFORMATION</Title>
      <RAMTemplateItem>
        <Letter>1a</Letter>
        <RamTemplateSectionNumber>1</RamTemplateSectionNumber>
        <Title>Non-routine or Log Page Number</Title>
      </RAMTemplateItem>
      <RAMTemplateItem>
        <Letter>1b</Letter>
        <RamTemplateSectionNumber>1</RamTemplateSectionNumber>
        <Title>PART 1 Revision Number</Title>
      </RAMTemplateItem>
    </RAMTemplateSection>
  </RAMTemplatePart>
  <RAM>
    <Id>26</Id>
    <CreatedBy>David</CreatedBy>
    <RAMPart1>
      <Id>21</Id>
      <RamId>26</RamId>
      <A1a>aaa</A1a>
      <A1b>bbb</A1b>
    </RAMPart1>
  </RAM>
</ResultSet>
```

**ThIS is my XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="ResultSet/RAMTemplatePart/RAMTemplateSection/RAMTemplateItem">
          <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="Letter"/>.
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            <input></input>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to dynamically populate the inputs so that, for example, where RAMTemplateItem's is 1a it will be populate with the data from RAMPart1 A1a, and 1b from A1b etc.
How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think one example is enough to establish a rule. Please explain exactly how to arrive at "A1a" from "1a". Where does the additional "A" character come from?

Comment: I will be satisfied with an answer to this problem only, because I'm stuck with this problem for now (I will try and learn from that). About the A, This is how the XML looks like (generated form the DB) and I can't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to lookup values from other nodes in the XML, you can usually make use of a "key".

In this case, it sounds like you want to look up child elements of the **RAMPart1**, whose name begin with the letter "A". So, you might write the key like this:

```
<xsl:key name="RAMPart1" 
         match="RAMPart1/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'A')]" 
         use="substring-after(local-name(), 'A')" />
```

This will allow you to look up such elements, but using the portion of the name after "A". For example `key('RAMPart1', '1a')` would return the element with the name "A1a". The second parameter doesn't have to be a fixed string, but can be the value of a node. For example, in your case, you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('RAMPart1', Letter)" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="RAMPart1" match="RAMPart1/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'A')]" use="substring-after(local-name(), 'A')" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="ResultSet/RAMTemplatePart/RAMTemplateSection/RAMTemplateItem">
          <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="Letter"/>.
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            <input>
               <xsl:value-of select="key('RAMPart1', Letter)" />
            </input>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```